# Checkbox is not checked while we click on the label in kendo-multiselect

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, angular7, kendo-multiselect

I am using the kendo-multiselect in angular 7. And everything is working except one condition.
When we Select an item label inside the select control and the corresponding checkbox is not selected. But when we Click on the checkbox then it is selected.

How can i Check the checkbox even i click on the Label.

You will find the working example here:

[https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rrnyvn?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts][1]

Thanks
Dileep

Answer (score 0):

Think you're missing a "**div**" like this:

```
<div class="k-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <label class="k-checkbox-label">{{ dataItem.ProductName }}</label>
</div>
```

Comment: I have added the <div class="k-checkbox"> but it is not working. the design also colapsed. Thanks